# Configuration system failed to initialize C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

My desktop App does not run due to an error of the configuration system which fails to initiate. 
the error is

System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.' ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy. (E:\visual studio projects\Windows form Application tutorials\Time Doctor App\Time Doctor App\bin\x86\Debug\Ezi Tasker 2.0.exe.Config line 18)

How can I fix this issue?
I have made many changes but it gives me an Error of the type of initializer  threw and exception.

The line is `Ezi Tasker 2.0.exe.Config line 18`

Here is my `App.config` file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
   <configSections>
   <section name="Signature" type="System.Configuration.IgnoreSectionHandler" />
  
  <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, 
  Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=tooken" >
  <section name="Time_Doctor_App.Properties.Settings" 
  type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
  PublicKeyToken=token" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" 
  />


</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Conec" connectionString="conecstring"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

 </connectionStrings>

<legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled='1'/>

<runtime>

<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

  <dependentAssembly>

    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="token" 
    culture="neutral" />

    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.5.0" newVersion="4.0.5.0" />

  </dependentAssembly>

  <dependentAssembly>

    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="token" culture="neutral" />

    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />

  </dependentAssembly>

</assemblyBinding>

  </runtime>
 <userSettings>
<Time_Doctor_App.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="User" serializeAs="String">
    <value />
  </setting>
  <setting name="Pass" serializeAs="String">
    <value />
  </setting>
</Time_Doctor_App.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: already have </userSettings></<configuration> at the end .only here is missing these tags

Answer (score 2):

The `<legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled='1'/>` element must be a child element of the `<runtime>` element, so move it there:

```
    </connectionStrings>

    <runtime>
       <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled='1'/>
       <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
```